# Creating a nodjs client for salesforce streaming api

Tags: apex, platform-event, streaming-api, heroku, node.js

I am trying to build a NodeJS app hosted on Heroku to subscribe to Salesforce Platform events. Now the problem is this app will not have any Webpage, just an app which should receive the events from SF 24/7. Is there any good advice on how to achieve this without the Webpage? 
Basically I am looking for an equivalent of EMP connector in nodejs.

Comment: A quick suggestion that isn't yet a fully fledged answer: use [Salesforce's NodeJS Streaming example app](https://github.com/heroku-examples/salesforce-streams-nodejs) and change the `OBSERVE_SALESFORCE_TOPIC_NAMES` runtime value to the API name of your configured platform event.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually not sure whether I really need to use a Redis pub/sub model with the nodejs client. All we are trying to do is capturing the events from salesforce and pass them to another server and then once we receive a response back from the server we need to update Salesforce. It is not critical to store the replayIds at this point.

Comment: Well, it's an open source reference implementation. Hack and slash as you see fit! :-)

Comment: I think this repo does exactly what you need: https://github.com/bhuone-garbu/faye_salesforce

Comment: Yeps thanks.. Thats all I needed. It uses the JS Faye client to receive the events.